# how to get value from a statement block of blockly in array?

Tags: javascript, visual-programming, blockly

I am working with Blockly , and I am quite new to that. I am having a statement block there under which I am able to add some other blocks. My problem is when I am trying to convert the statement block using `Blockly.JavaScript.statementToCode(block, 'io_fields')` it is returning string for all the blocks combined I want it in pieces, like in an array. I don't whether this is possible or not. I didn't find any API in their documentation.

Please suggest me the way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Blockly adds all of the statement blocks up. So if you do this (from `blocks_compressed` `text_print`):

```
print "Hello world"
print "Hello world"
```

Blocks return

```
'window.alert("Hello world");\nwindow.alert("Hello world")'
```

So you can simply do this:

```
Blockly.JavaScript.statementToCode(block, 'io_fields').split(';\n');
```